# How to build a query to retrieve data based on column names that stored in table

Tags: sql, db2

Sorry im a newbie in db2sql and i dont know whether my question is logic or not. Please correct if im wrong, thanks.

I have a table looks like this :

```
TABLE NAME : TABLE_FRUIT

FRUIT_ID    FRUIT_NAME     FRUIT_PRICE
---------------------------------------
   1          Apple            1
   2          Orange           2
   3          Banana           1
```

I stored column name (FRUIT_PRICE) and table name `TABLE_FRUIT` in `TABLE_ALL`
 by using this query.

`select tabname,colname from SYSCAT.columns where tabname='TB_FRUIT'` , once i get the data i break it and stored in `TABLE_ALL`

```
TABLE NAME : TABLE_ALL

TABLE_ID     TABLE NAME     TABLE_COLUMN 
----------------------------------------
   1         TABLE_FRUIT     FRUIT_PRICE
```

### Question

- Is it possible to obtained`FRUIT_PRICE` value from `TABLE_FRUIT` which is under `TABLE_ALL`?
- how it is possible to write a query to obtain the value ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You'd need dynamic SQL to do this.  There are various examples in other RDBMSs.  What are you trying to do here (big picture)?  What's the point of a query like this, when you don't appear to be storing something that says the column is a number (much less _why_ you want the particular column)?  These kinds of dynamic setups generally aren't as useful as people want...

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic SQL can solves your problem

```
declare @colname nvarchar(30) = (select top 1 COLUMN_NAME from  table_all where tabname='TB_FRUIT')

declare @sql nvarchar(30)

set @sql='select ' +@colname +' from TB_FRUIT'

exec(@sql)
```

It will gives only first column of the table TB_FRUIT

By this all values under @colname(ie: FRUIT_PRICE) will be displayed

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering.  i got error whenever i declared this code in java/ jsp `declare @colname nvarchar(30)` this symbol cannot be use @

Comment: That is SQL Server notation, not DB2's SQL PL.